# Why does the script get stuck on executing a while loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, while-loop

I was trying something in Google Apps Script for my Google Sheets spreadsheet.  It basically just copies cells in one sheet, goes to another sheet, pastes it, which updates a bunch of data, then it copies those values, and goes back to the original sheet and transposes those results.

So I had it working as a macro, but I'd like to make it function in a loop, so it fills out all of the rows on a sheet. Below is a copy of my code:

```
function relcoprow() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var startloc = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
var rangetocopy = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0,0,1,2);
var countnewcell = 1
var nextcell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(countnewcell,0,1,1);
  while (nextcell!="") {
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet4'), true);
  rangetocopy.copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange("A2"));
  spreadsheet.getRange('V1');

  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('W1').activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getRange('V3:V1130').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('W3:W1130'), 
  SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  var rangetotranspose = spreadsheet.getRange('W3:W1130');

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);
  rangetotranspose.copyTo(startloc.offset(0,7,1,1130), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, 
  true);
  nextcell = nextcell +1 
    }
  };
```

When I run the code it get's stuck on this line and doesn't move forward. Because it gets stuck I can 't even see if my while loop works.

Can anyone offer advice on what I should do?

Comment: `offset` returns an instance of `Range` class, which inherits from `Object`. Objects in JavaScript are truthy.  `{} + 1 === 1` (due to conversion rules), so each iteration simply adds `1` to the integer stored in `nextcell` since the second iteration. And ints will never be equal to an empty string. Therefore, `nextcell!=""` is always `true`, hence the loop is stuck in `while(true)` endless cycle.

Comment: @OlegValter actually if you check in Apps Script, the result of `nextcell + 1` is `"Range1"` and as it loops it becomes `"Range11"`, `"Range111"` and so on.  Absolutely right that it is always true, just thought it was interesting that it is coereced into a string.

Comment: @dwmorrin - sorry, my bad, indeed it is (I just inferred from what I remember about coercion). The reasoning still applies, though, but needs a revision, thank you. I expected the `Range` class to have a `valueOf` method, should've checked

Comment: @foose212 - we've pointing out why your `while` loop condition will never be false, but if you want to see this result for yourself, try [using the debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints) in the script editor.  But the loop should run... there's nothing about "getting past a VAR" as your title says... maybe you could define what your trying to accomplish with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the complex copying?

Comment: @dwmorrin, agreed, it should run, albeit perpetually. foose212, despite the fact that you need to fix the `nextcell` in the first place (maybe this is just a typo, and you wanted to incement `countnewcell` instead and offset a cell further on each iteration?), the loop should endlessly copy data until hitting execution limits...

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.  I see the problem with nextcell, I changed that line to countnewcell =  countnewcell +1.  I'm sorry I didn't make my problem clear in the first post.  I kept getting rejected, so I must of taken out a part of the problem in one of my revisions.  The code runs, but it seems to get stuck on the line right above the line var rangetotranspose.  I can see the macro work, it copies my initial values, pastes it into sheet 4, then copies the new values and pastes it into the correct column.  Then selects that column, and gets stuck there.  Any help?

Comment: BTW I am trying to make the function look at the next row to see if it has a value in it, if it does I want the macro to run on the new row until all rows are complete

Comment: @foose212 - what do you mean by getting rejected, btw? Re:stuck - thank you for explainging that (edit the correct code into the question, so as others won't get confused). That said,, could you elaborate on what "stuck" means here? Does it perpetually run? Are there any logs? Errors? Basically, how do you know it is really stuck? Try adding a `console.log` method call somewhere above and below the offending line to see if the line is reached at all

Comment: Apart from clarifying what `stuck` and `rejected` means, could you by any chance provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on, free of sensitive information, so that your issue can be better understood?

Comment: @OlegValter So I can watch the script run on the spreadsheet since it's a macro.  When it goes to sheet 4 it pastes in appropriate , and copies the new data and puts it where I need it.  Then it highlights the new column, but it never moves beyond that point.  I can see on the top of the sheet the script is running at that point.  I have to cancel the script there to break the loop, but I can't figure out what's going on.  I just pout in consol.log() below where I think it is stuck.

Comment: @lamblichus yes, I'd be happy to share the sheet.  What's the best way to do that?

Comment: @OlegValter never mind about the stuck part.  That's was me just not understanding the code.  My old code was activating cells with each step, and I didn't have another activation to go back to my first sheet.  I actually just removed all of my active() function out so it doesn't bounce around from sheet to sheet.  I also figured out how to move my cell down one after the function completes. I'm now trying to fix the while loop, so it keeps moving down all of my rows until there is nothing left.

Comment: @foose212 - no worries, glad you resolved it - I've edited your answer a little to look more like a proper answer to the question - if you have some time to expand upon it a bit to be even more useful to others, would bwe great.

Answer (score 0):

So my loop wasn't stuck. It was just because I didn't have a bit of code to go back to sheet1.

However, all of the help with the while loop really moved me a long after I figured out the problem with `active()`. My loop now works.

I used the code to go down to the next row after each iteration and make that the active cell.

For my `while` loop I used `!tickerloc.isblank()` to let the program know that it needed to keep working.